# MariaDB - So many threads?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm on a test VM based on VMWare with MariaDB + nginx installed; when looking with `htop` this is the situation:

[image: htop output]

So we have 26 threads under the main process.

I know that inactive threads doesn't impact so much in memory / performaces, but for my "know how", is there a way (parameters?) to reduce the number of child threads under MariaDB / MySQL?

Googling around I've found something related to `max_connections` and `thread_concurrency` parameters that I've set both to 5 but once restarted nothing changed.

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: An active server will have dozens, hundreds, or even thousands of threads.  I would suggest that you're looking at an entirely uninteresting and very small number, with only 26.

Comment: There is a low overhead for threads which is why they are used. Its not worth spending too much effort reducing them unless you have a specific problem traced back to threads.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have had some activity, I think the number of threads varies between

```
(misc) + thread_cache_size
(misc) + max_connections
```

`thread_concurrency` was specific to Solaris 8, and has been removed from newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB.

Where `(misc)` is 1 for the main process plus replication slave threads plus innodb read/write/purge threads.  (Thanks danblack)

Comment: + replication slave threads + innodb read/write/purge threads.

Answer (score 0):

Per current Maria DB reference manual,

From MariaDB 10.2.0, the default is automatically set to the smaller of either 256, or the max_connections size.

Consider leaving it out of your my.cnf or my.ini for auto sizing.